# Mongoose fill defaults with aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm not sure if this is intentional or not, but I cannot seem to make defaults work for `aggregate()`. For example, if I add a new field to the schema:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ sessionIds: { type: [String], default: [] } });
export.User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

and run the query on existing documents (which don't have this field yet)

```js
const users = await User.find({}).exec();
console.log(users[0].sessionIds);
```

This will print an empty array correctly. However, when I run the same query, but using `aggregate`, it prints undefined.

```js
const users = await User.aggregate({ $match: {} }).exec();
console.log(users[0].sessionIds);
```

Is there a way I can tell Mongoose to apply the default values for the aggregation or apply it to the results after the aggregation ran?

Edit: After experimenting a bit more, I figured out that it has to do something with `aggregate` returning lean results, while `find` returning Mongoose objects. Is there a way to make `aggregate` return mongoose objects as well?

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate ->  aggregate ->The documents returned are plain javascript objects, not mongoose documents (since any shape of document can be returned).

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar yeah, that's what I found as well. Is there a way to fill these values using Mongoose (e.g., by a utility function or something like that)? There are many queries that can only be done with `aggregate` and if I cannot fill the default values for those, it can break many things.

Comment: You can try `new User(user)`, but not sure how well it will work, it's bit hacky.

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar that was it, thanks!